# C++ --- error C2664: 'int scanf(const char *,...)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'int' to 'const char *'

Tags: c++, scanf

I'm very new to C++ and I'm trying to build this very simple code, but I don't understand why I get this error:

```
Error   1   error C2664: 'int scanf(const char *,...)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'int' to 'const char *'
```

Here is the code:

```
// lab.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h> 

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int row = 0;
    printf("Please enter the number of rows: ");
    scanf('%d', &row);
    printf("here is why you have entered %d", row);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is not C++. Not with that error message.

Comment: Single quotes to make a character constant, double quotes to make a string literal. So it should be `"%d"`.

Comment: well its is C but I run it with Visual Studio and a C++ compiler.

Comment: Ugh I'm dumb. It's not a single character. I hate being dumb. You really should choose one language tag based on the language you're using, but sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change `scanf('%d', &row);` to

```
scanf("%d", &row);
```

`'%d'` is a multicharacter literal which is of type `int`.

`"%d"` on the other hand is a string literal, which is compatible with the `const char *` as expected by `scanf` first argument.

If you pass single quoted `%d`, compiler would try to do an implicit conversion from `int`(type of `'%d'`) to `const char *` (as expected by scanf) and will fail as no such conversion exist.

Comment: lol ok that was easy ! sorry for asking such a simple question :/

Comment: No problems. I would be glad if it helps you.

Comment: Sorry, I jumped to the wrong tag. I slightly changed the answer to fit C++.

Answer (score 1):

Hope you understood your error by now.And you have done this code in C and not in C++.You need to include the header iostream ...

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        int row = 0;
        cout<<"Please enter the number of rows: ";
        cin>>row;
        cout<<"entered value"<<row;

    }
```

Hope this helps..!

Comment: This is clever and releavant. +1